# How to assign a random values to a variable when a pattern of dates are matched in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a sample data frame like given below :

```
         id                date
          1 2007-04-14 03:56:12
          1 2007-04-14 03:57:13
          1 2007-04-14 03:57:18
          1 2007-04-14 03:57:19
          1 2007-04-14 03:58:04
          1 2007-04-14 04:06:12
          1 2016-07-09 10:52:12
          1 2016-07-09 10:53:13
          1 2016-07-09 10:53:18
          1 2016-07-09 10:53:19
          1 2016-07-09 10:54:04
          1 2016-07-09 11:02:12
          1 2008-10-11 12:16:12
          1 2008-10-11 12:17:13
          1 2008-10-11 12:17:18
          1 2008-10-11 12:17:19
          1 2008-10-11 12:18:04
          1 2008-10-11 12:26:12
```

for each date in the dates columns there is pattern like example in date column

```
 2007-04-14 03:56:12
 2007-04-14 03:57:13
 2007-04-14 03:57:18
 2007-04-14 03:57:19
 2007-04-14 03:58:04
 2007-04-14 04:06:12
```

for this i need a random number for id column. Random number should be between 1 to 8(1:8).

Expected output should look like this:

```
 id                date
  1 2007-04-14 03:56:12
  1 2007-04-14 03:57:13
  1 2007-04-14 03:57:18
  1 2007-04-14 03:57:19
  1 2007-04-14 03:58:04
  1 2007-04-14 04:06:12
  7 2016-07-09 10:52:12
  7 2016-07-09 10:53:13
  7 2016-07-09 10:53:18
  7 2016-07-09 10:53:19
  7 2016-07-09 10:54:04
  7 2016-07-09 11:02:12
  6 2008-10-11 12:16:12
  6 2008-10-11 12:17:13
  6 2008-10-11 12:17:18
  6 2008-10-11 12:17:19
  6 2008-10-11 12:18:04
  6 2008-10-11 12:26:12
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected output

Comment: You just want a column of random numbers between 1 and 8? `sample(x = 1:8, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)`

Comment: please share your data using `dput(data)` and the code you have tried to help solve this problem.

Comment: Shabeer, it seems like your "pattern" is a little unclear or under-defined. Do you mean "*dates that are closely-spaced*"? If so, what happens if two groupings occurred on the same day, do you think "more than an hour different" will always be correct?

Comment: Yes, dates that are closely spaced(also based on for each day assign one id)  . It ok if i have a two same days with an hour difference. Output like 1 for 2007-04-14 3 for 2016-07-09 and 2 for 2008-10-11

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pattern actually refer to unique date,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
> (uniquedate = unique(date(test$dat)))
[1] "2007-04-14" "2016-07-09" "2008-10-11"
> (key = sample(uniquedate))
[1] "2016-07-09" "2008-10-11" "2007-04-14"
> test %>% 
+   mutate(date = date(dat), newid = match(date, key))
# A tibble: 18 x 4
      id dat                 date       newid
   <dbl> <dttm>              <date>     <int>
 1     1 2007-04-14 03:56:12 2007-04-14     3
 2     1 2007-04-14 03:57:13 2007-04-14     3
 3     1 2007-04-14 03:57:18 2007-04-14     3
 4     1 2007-04-14 03:57:19 2007-04-14     3
 5     1 2007-04-14 03:58:04 2007-04-14     3
 6     1 2007-04-14 04:06:12 2007-04-14     3
 7     1 2016-07-09 10:52:12 2016-07-09     1
 8     1 2016-07-09 10:53:13 2016-07-09     1
 9     1 2016-07-09 10:53:18 2016-07-09     1
10     1 2016-07-09 10:53:19 2016-07-09     1
11     1 2016-07-09 10:54:04 2016-07-09     1
12     1 2016-07-09 11:02:12 2016-07-09     1
13     1 2008-10-11 12:16:12 2008-10-11     2
14     1 2008-10-11 12:17:13 2008-10-11     2
15     1 2008-10-11 12:17:18 2008-10-11     2
16     1 2008-10-11 12:17:19 2008-10-11     2
17     1 2008-10-11 12:18:04 2008-10-11     2
18     1 2008-10-11 12:26:12 2008-10-11     2
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct but can you replace the values of id column as newid column. id column should be random values from 1 to 8(1:8).  And also i don't need two new date and newid columns.

Comment: Is 8 a arbitrary number of the levels of different dates? If latter, the above code shall account for that. Also please check basic R data transformation for selecting variables/columns and rename columns.

Comment: yes, 1:8 is a random number need to assign to unique dates. I have a bid data with many dates not only the above given. Can you help me to solve this problem, please.

Comment: for my dataframe with match() function the values are going upto 17 but i only need values between 1:8